# using jQuery slideUp causes "jumpy" interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the demo link below, I am using jQuery slideUp and you will notice after it slides up, there is a quick jump of the content.

Do you know why this is? My html is valid (with the exception of the select option not having a label attribute..which I am still figuring out...). Do I have something positioned incorrectly?

http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com/index.php

(Click login --> Sales -->Show Item Grid THEN Hide Item Grid to see the bug)

Answer (score 2):

this inline style

```
<div style="margin-top: 39px;" id="content">
```

and line *724* of *unicorn.css*

```
#content {
   ...
   margin-top: -39px; 
   ...
}
```

... are conflicting with each other.

If you remove both, the page doesn't jump.

Answer (score 0):

You have set a `margin-top` on the content `div` of 39px. This is only visible when you slide down the item grid. It seems to 'jump' when sliding back up because of this margin. Try setting the margin to 0px;

```
<div id="content" style="margin-top:0px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around a little bit and this is being caused by the `margin-top:39px` on your #content div, if you remove that and use `top:39px` instead of `margin-top:39px` on the `#content` element instead it doesn't jerk either - but it also causes the button to jump a bit on slideUp and slideDown so you will need to tweak the css of the button wrapper area like so:

To fix the button jumping issue:

```
#show_hide_grid_wrapper {
position: relative;
text-align: right;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As prev. answers mention, you have `margin-top 39px` on `#content`. Setting it to 0 will solve the problem, but it will also remove your beautiful dark gray section above the content. To get it back, add this to your CSS:

```
#content:before {
content: '';
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 39px;
background: YOUR GRAY COLOR;
}
```